# How to According to SQL SERVER database changes generate sql statement every day

Tags: sql-server

I don't know if SQL SERVER have this feature.
Operation over a period of time,you can export the corresponding sql statement script.contain "insert,update,delete,alter table etc".

For example:Every night,I open generated .sql file,I can see full day operation.in this file,contains many sql statement as follow

```
insert into ...
update ....
delete ...
create table ...
drop table ...
alter table ...
```

My English is not better,please forgive me.
Thanks.

Comment: There is the possibility to use SQL Server Profiler which allows you to specify which statements it should log per database. This can also be written directly into a file or a table.

Comment: What problem are you attempting to solve by logging all your queries?

Answer (score 0):

No - sql server does not provide this functionality. But at the others suggest, perhaps your goal can be achieved in a different fashion.